# Storing command result in variable changes result

Tags: bash

I am trying to do a multi-line regex with a grep to find and remove certain ESLint comments from a javascript file (I don't think the fact that it is javascript is incredibly relevant, just providing context).

With the help of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717772/regex-grep-for-multi-line-search-needed?noredirect=1&lq=1) I learned about using -Pzo to use Perl regex, put null characters at the end of each match instead of a newline (essentially treat the whole file as one line), and only output the matching portions. Together, these options give me the following command:
`grep -Pzo '(?s)\s*\/\* globals .*?\*\/' "file.js"`

When I run this command from a terminal, I get the output I expect. For example:

```
/* globals text text */
/* globals text text */
/* globals text text */
/* globals text text */
/* globals text */
/* globals text */
/* globals text */
/* globals text */
/* globals text */
/* globals ...
        ... */
```

I want to run this command in bash script and store the result in an array. From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7180082/grep-output-into-array) I learned how to create an array from the command output, and I came up with this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
matches=( $(grep -Pzo '(?s)\s*\/\* globals .*?\*\/' "file.js") )
for m in "${matches[@]}"; do
    echo "${m}"
done
```

But when I run this script, the output of the echo looks like this:

```
/bin
/boot
/dev
/etc
/home
/init
... more directories, then it repeats
/bin
...
```

Is there some subtle difference between how the grep is running in the terminal versus the script that I'm missing? Running `bash --version` from my terminal and in the script reports

```
GNU bash, version 5.0.17(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's this line:

```sh
matches=( $(grep -Pzo '(?s)\s*\/\* globals .*?\*\/' "file.js") )
```

Because the output of the command substitution is unquoted, the shell will apply word splitting and filename expansion (read [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/4667) for all the details).

Clearly `/*` and `*/` will expand to a bunch of files.

To read the *lines of output* of a command into an array, use `mapfile` with input redirected from a process substitution:

```sh
mapfile -t matches < <(grep ...)
```